# Async firebase call inside vuejs2 http interceptors

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, http-headers, vue-resource

Using Firebase authentication and VueJS2 HTTP interceptors I want to add the IDToken to the header if the request so I don't have to manually do it everytime. I'm sending the request to a NodeJS API so I can see the headers of the resquest once it gets there. Here's the part of the main.js where I push the interceptor :

```js
Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
  auth.currentUser
    .getIdToken()
    .then(token => {
      request.headers.set("Authorization", token);
      request.headers.set("Accept", "application/json");
      next();
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
});
```

If I do it as written above, the resquest is sent but the header is not set. If I do something like this then the header is sent :

```js
Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
  request.headers.set("Authorization", "TEST");
  request.headers.set("Accept", "application/json");
  next();
});
```

So I would think that it is a problem with the fact that the getIdToken() method is async, but I see no way to make it work unless I take that code outside of the intercptor, something I would like to avoid. Any idea on how to do this properly?

Comment: Vue has no HTTP interceptors. The question is specific to the plugin you're using, it should be addressed.

Comment: I'm using VueResource. Maybe that's why I found nothing on the subject I was looking for vuejs interceptor. Thanks for the cue hopefully it'll help me find what I'm looking for!

Comment: I can see it's poorly documented, in contrast to Axios. I can't say if `next` works as expected here. It likely isn't, considering the result. Try to remove the mentions of it and return a promise from interceptor function instead, this seems to be supported, at least in the latest lib version.

Comment: It seems `next` was removed after [1.4.0](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/releases/tag/1.4.0) and it seems there is no way to do asynchronous inside interceptor. See [this](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/issues/675)

Comment: Turns out I decided to do like the guy in that comment and use axios instead. Much more instinctive, well documented so less problems on the long term and works as you'd expect. Thanks for the help guys!